# Unexpected echoing when using raw_input() with map

Tags: python, python-2.7

While [Code golfing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/11250/rosetta-stone-challenge-draw-a-box-plot), I though of using the following code to read few lines of data from stdin

```
D:\>cat box.py
n=int(raw_input().split('=')[-1])
data=map(raw_input,range(n))
D:\>box.py
3
01
12
23
```

To my surprise, it kept on echoing a sequence of numbers every time data was read from stdin

On changing the above code to use LC, the problem was not existing.

```
D:\>cat box.py
n=int(raw_input().split('=')[-1])
data=[raw_input() for _ in range(n)]
D:\>box.py
3
1
2
3
```

Any idea what could be the reason?

Comment: Why not: `data=[raw_input()for _ in[1]*n]`?

Comment: @Bakuriu Better yet: `data=map(raw_input,['']*n)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`raw_input()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) takes an optional argument, the prompt, that gets written to stdout. You are supplying that argument by your use of `map()`.

Answer (score -2):

I think the reason is the second block of code has the for loop in it, while the first doesn't have such restrictions

Comment: Unless you clarify your answer, it's wrong so that's why you were down voted.